# Sed working from the command line but not within a Python script

Tags: python, linux, sed

I'm trying to run the following command in a Python script:

```
sudo sed -i 's/auth-user-pass/auth-user-pass \/etc\/openvpn\/credentials/g' /etc/openvpn/US-East.ovpn
```

The command above runs fine in a terminal.

My Python script looks like this;

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(["sudo", "sed", "-i", "'s/auth-user-pass/auth-user-pass", "\/etc\/openvpn\/credentials/g'", "/etc/openvpn/US-East.ovpn"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
```

But I get the following error when I run the script

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''
```

I thought some characters (like the single quote) might need escaping but I've been trying and none of them work.

I'm quite lost; can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

Since your command line is:

```
sudo sed -i 's/auth-user-pass/auth-user-pass \/etc\/openvpn\/credentials/g' /etc/openvpn/US-East.ovpn
```

You need to remove the single quotes (the shell does that for you) and you need to keep the whole of the single-quoted argument as one argument, not splitting it at spaces (the shell doesn't split at spaces inside a quoted string):

```
subprocess.Popen(["sudo", "sed", "-i", "s/auth-user-pass/auth-user-pass \/etc\/openvpn\/credentials/g", "/etc/openvpn/US-East.ovpn"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
```

The `sed` command does not expect to see the single quotes.

Comment: Hey @Jonathan thanks for helping me out. I now get the error `sed: -e expression #1, char 31: unterminated `s' command` I'm not sure what the S command is. The Sed documentation is quite knarly

Comment: Ok so I figured it out, the answer was this answer and the answer below - so removing the single quotes and removing the commas in the sed command parameter. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can you test this without the commas in the sed command parameter?

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(["sudo", "sed", "-i", "'s/auth-user-pass/auth-user-pass \/etc\/openvpn\/credentials/g'", "/etc/openvpn/US-East.ovpn"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license (2.5/3.0/4.0)](//stackoverflow.com/help/licensing), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: Hey @cigien Ok so I figured it out, the answer was this answer and the answer above - so removing the single quotes and removing the commas in the sed command parameter. Thanks